# Calculate ELO Rating Expected Score

Tags: code-golf, math

Your task is to calculate the expected chance of winning for 2 players in some game, each with their own **[ELO Rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system#Mathematical_details)**. Player A has ELO R<sub>a</sub> and player B has ELO R<sub>b</sub>

The expected score for Player A (E<sub>a</sub>) is: 1 / (1 + 10<sup>(R<sub>b</sub> - R<sub>a</sub>) / 400</sup>). There is a similar equation for Player B (E<sub>b</sub>): 1 / (1 + 10<sup>(R<sub>a</sub> - R<sub>b</sub>) / 400</sup>).

If you want a more copiable version: `1 / (1 + 10^((a-b) / 400))`

E<sub>a</sub> + E<sub>b</sub> should be equal to 1.

Therefore, the score for a player is their expected chance of winning some match, in decimal.

Your program/function should take 2 inputs, Player A's ELO, and Player B's ELO, and print/return their respective chance to win in decimal format. The output *must* add up to one, and you must be accurate to at least 5 decimal places (`0.00000`). After 5 decimal places, you may have inaccurate digits, provided the two outputs still add up to one.

#### Examples:

```
1200 2100 -> 0.005591967 0.994408033
1 1 -> 0.5 0.5
60 20 -> 0.557312 0.442688
9999 9998 -> 0.501439 0.498561
9999 1 -> 0.999999 0.000001
```

In the final test case, some answers use scientific exponentiation to represent the value. This is not valid.

You can see in test case 3 here that `0.557312` is not quite accurate, because the `2` should be a `1`, but this is fine because it is after five decimal places and the outputs still add up to one.

This is an example of invalid output:

```
9999 9998 -> 0.5014391117091516, 0.49856088829084844
```

This looks like it satisfies the requirements at first glance, but the numbers add up to `1.00000000000000004` and therefore the output is not valid.

Trailing zeroes in the output is fine.

You may assume a player's ELO will always be greater than 0, and nobody will have an ELO higher than 9999.

The input and output format is flexible, but the input and output must still be in base 10.

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the answer with the lowest byte count will win!

Comment: +1 for ELO rating, even though I was disappointed to find you are talking about something called Elo rating instead.

Comment: You should also add the test case `[9999, 998]` which most answers seem to fail for.

Comment: @Emigna added, but made it more extreme ;)

Comment: @Okx: Nice. Need to go back to the drawing board to handle that one :)

Comment: It seems all answers fail on `9999, 1` including my own, so I can't post it :-(

Comment: In fact, I think your example case is invalid: http://i.imgur.com/aMj7pjG.png

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
÷400⁵*÷S$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@394u4mBwaPGrVqHtwer/P//P9rQyMBAR8HI0MAgFgA) or [View all test cases.](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@394u4mBwaPGrVqHtwer/D/c/qhpjfv//9HRhkYGBjoKRoYGBrE6CtGGOgqGINoMJAYWsQQCHQUgYREbCwA)

The input is an array `[Ra, Rb]` and the output is an array `[Ea, Eb]`.

### Explanation

```
÷400⁵*÷S$  Input: array [Ra, Rb]
÷400       Divide each by 400, makes [Ra/400, Rb/400]
    ⁵*     Raise 10 to that power, makes [10^(Ra/400), 10^(Rb/400)]
        $  Monadic chain operating on previous result
      ÷      Divide each by
       S     The sum of the whole
           Makes [10^(Ra/400)/(10^(Ra/400) + 10^(Rb/400)),
                  10^(Rb/400)/(10^(Ra/400) + 10^(Rb/400))]
               = [1/(1 + 10^((Rb-Ra)/400)), 1/(1 + 10^((Ra-Rb)/400))]
```

Comment: [What is going on here?](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@394u4mBwaPGrVqHtwer/P//P9oSCHQUDGMB)

Comment: @Okx That is scientific notation. I'm sure you know what it is since you just edited the challenge to require standard notation after you originally said input/output format were up to us.

Comment: Did you look at the other output? It's 1.0!

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>55</s> 47 bytes

```
lambda a,b:[1/(1+10**(x/400))for x in[b-a,a-b]]
```

-8 bytes thanks to @math_junkie

Comment: Why not use a for comprehension: `1/(1+10**(x/400))for x in [b-a,a-b]`

Comment: @math_junkie It's called a "[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)"

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, 11 bytes

```
10i400/^ts/
```

Takes input as a list and outputs a list.

```
10       % push number literal
i        % push input
400      % push number literal
/        % divide the list (by 400)
^        % power (10^list, element wise)
t        % duplicate the list
s        % sum the second one
/        % divide by the sum
         % (implicit) convert to string and display
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>41</s> 35 bytes

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to @Neil*

```
a=>b=>[b=1/(1+10**((b-a)/400)),1-b]
```

Comment: Since Ea + Eb = 1, just write `a=>b=>[b=1/(1+10**((b-a)/400)),1-b]`.

Comment: @Neil Really? I'm so shortsighted :P Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 23 bytes

```
XAq~_W%\.m400df/f#:)f/p
```

Some other 23 byte solutions:

```
q~_W%\.m400df{/A\#)W#}p
Aq~_W%\.m400df/f{#)W#}p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@x/hWFgXH64ao5drYmCQkqafpmylmaZf8P9/tKGRgYGCkaGBQSwA)

**Explanation**

```
X                        Push 1
 A                       Push 10
  q~                     Push an eval the input, a list containing 2 numbers
    _W%                  Duplicate the list and reverse it
       \                 Swap top stack elements, so the order of answers matches the input
        .m               Vectorized subtraction: computes Ra - Rb and Rb - Ra
          400d           Push 400.0 (must be a double, otherwise / performs integer division)
              f/         Divide both values by 400
                f#       Raise 10 to the power of both numbers
                  :)     Increment both numbers
                    f/   Divide 1 by both numbers
                      p  Output the list nicely
```

Comment: Fails on `9999, 1` :(

Comment: @Metoniem That's odd... it definitely has something to do with rounding issues, or maybe something like how `0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004`. I'll look into it

Comment: it actually looks fine now, ALL answers including Google's calculator return the same result as your code. I'm quite sure the test case is invalid :(

Answer (score 1):

## C, 63 bytes

```
#define M(a,b)1/(1+pow(10,(a-b)/400.)),1/(1+pow(10,(b-a)/400.))
```

Defines a (rather naive) parameterized macro `M`, the shortest working approach I could think of but probably still not the shortest. As such, any golfing suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Anyways, this returns 2 floating point values, `E_b` and `E_a`, respectively.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@6@ckpqWmZeq4KuRqJOkaaivYahdkF@uYWigo5Gom6Spb2JgoKepqYMikaSbCJP4n5lXopCbmJmnoalQzaUABAVFQKE0DSXVNAXVtJg8JR1fDUMjAwMdI0MDA01Na67a/wA)

Comment: Fails on `9999, 1`

Comment: @Metoniem Yup. Most likely has to do with how C rounds floats. :/ I'm looking into it.

Comment: It actually seems to be correct, the test case might be invalid :(

Comment: Suggest `exp10(x)` instead of `pow(10,x)`

Answer (score 0):

## SAS Macro Language, 70 bytes

```
%macro e(a,b);data t;p=1/(1+10**((&b-&a)/400));q=1-p;proc print%mend;
```

Output is a SAS data set where variables `p` and `q` are the players' chance of winning. 11 bytes can be saved by removing the `print` procedure.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 92 bytes

Not the shortest, but it's C#, never the shortest..

## Golfed

```
   static double[]f(int a,double b){b=1/(1+System.Math.Pow(10,(a-b)/400d));return new[]{1-b,b};
```

### Ungolfed

```
static double[] f(int a, double b)
{
    b = 1/(1 + System.Math.Pow(10, (a - b)/400d));
    return new[] {1 - b, b};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## q, 26 bytes

```
{1%1+10 xexp(y-x;x-y)%400}
```

Example

```
q){1%1+10 xexp(y-x;x-y)%400}[1200;2100]
0.0055919673088347735 0.99440803269116518
```