# Elo Rating Calculator

Tags: code-golf, math

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110825/calculate-elo-rating-expected-score)

### Task

Your task is to calculate the new [Elo rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) ([FIDE rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system#FIDE_ratings)) for a player after winning, losing or drawing a game of chess.

To calculate the Elo rating two formulas are needed:

```
R' = R0 + K*(S - E)
E = 1 / (1 + 10 ^ ((R1 - R0) / 400))
```

where:

- `R'` is the new rating for player0,
- `R0` is the current rating of player0 and `R1` is the current rating of player1,
- `S` is the score of the game: `1` if player0 wins, `0` if player0 loses or
  `0.5` if player0 draws,
- `K` = `40` if the given history has a length < 30, even if it exceeds 2400
- `K` = `20` if the given history has a length >= 30 and never exceeds 2400 (<2400),
- `K` = `10` if the given history has a length >= 30 and exceeds 2400 at any point (>=2400)

(if history has a length < 30 but a max value >= 2400 `K` will equal 40)

### Input

- History of player0's ratings as an array of positive integers greater than 0, where the last item is the players current rating. If no history is given, the current rating will be 1000
- Rating of player1 as an integer
- Score, either 1, 0 or 0.5

### Output

`R'`, A decimal integer of player0's new rating

### Examples

```
input: [], 1500, 1
  K = 40 (length of history is less than 30) 
  E = 1 / (1 + 10 ^ ((1500 - 1000) / 400)) = 0.0532
  R' = 1000 + 40*(1 - 0.0532) = 1038
output: 1038

input: [1000, 1025, 1050, 1075, 1100, 1125, 1150, 1175, 1200, 1225, 1250, 1275, 1300, 1325, 1350, 1375, 1400, 1425, 1450, 1475, 1500, 1525, 1550, 1575, 1600, 1625, 1650, 1675, 1700, 1725], 1000, 0
  K = 20 (length of history is more than 30 but never exceeds 2400)
  E = 1 / (1 + 10 ^ ((1000 - 1725) / 400)) = 0.9848
  R' = 1725 + 20*(0 - 0.9848) = 1705
output: 1705

input: [1000, 1025, 1050, 1075, 1100, 1125, 1150, 1175, 1200, 1225, 1250, 1275, 1300, 1325, 1350, 1375, 1400, 1425, 1450, 1475, 1500, 1525, 1550, 1575, 1600, 1625, 1650, 1800, 2100, 2500], 2200, 0.5
  K = 10 (length of history is more than 30 and exceeds 2400)
  E = 1 / (1 + 10 ^ ((2200 - 2500) / 400)) = 0.8490
  R' = 2500 + 10*(0.5 - 0.8490) = 2497
output: 2497
```

### Test cases:

```
[2256,25,1253,1278,443,789], 3999, 0.5 -> 809
[783,1779,495,1817,133,2194,1753,2169,834,521,734,1234,1901,637], 3291, 0.5 -> 657
[190,1267,567,2201,2079,1058,1694,112,780,1182,134,1077,1243,1119,1883,1837], 283, 1 -> 1837
[1665,718,85,1808,2546,2193,868,3514,436,2913,6,654,797,2564,3872,2250,2597,1208,1928,3478,2359,3909,581,3892,1556,1175,2221,3996,3346,238], 2080, 1 -> 248
[1543,2937,2267,556,445,2489,2741,3200,528,964,2346,3467,2831,3746,3824,2770,3207,613,2675,1692,2537,1715,3018,2760,2162,2038,2637,741,1849,41,193,458,2292,222,2997], 3814, 0.5 -> 3002
```

## Notes

You won't get an input with fewer scores than 30 and a maximum score higher than 2400

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: I'm assuming `len(history)<30` and `max(history)>2400` is either impossible, or results in `K=40`?

Comment: @StewieGriffin That is possible and does result in K=40

Comment: Is it though? In reality?

Comment: Can we assume that the player's history will never have 0?

Comment: @StewieGriffin From my understanding from the [official FIDE website](https://ratings.fide.com/calculator_rtd.phtml) I believe it is.

Comment: @Arjun I'm not sure officially, but for this challenge yes, you can assume a player's rating and history will always be > 0

Comment: @StewieGriffin Tested your code and it works for the test cases I provided, so it looks to be fine

Comment: Note: According to the FIDE-scoring system: If you play 41 games against a player having a score of 5000 (more than 2000 points higher than the highest achieved score ever), you'll end up with a score of **2400**. I believe that fewer scores than 30, and a maximum score higher than 2400 should be considered invalid input (but that's OP's decision). There might be solutions that will get `k!=40` for such an input (it's not one of the current test cases).

Comment: @StewieGriffin Oh right, I see what you mean, if you start with 1000 there's no way to reach 2400 in under 30 games. I'll change the test cases.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Yep, but a few of the test cases have less 30 scores and a maximum higher than 2400, so they'll need to be changed :)

Comment: @Tom, ah, I see... :)

Comment: @Arjun "Output: R', An integer of player0's new rating", integer usually means a whole, rounded number ;) So I would say you need to have them rounded

Comment: @Arjun You'll have to round to match the test cases, I believe it's rounded when officially calculating the Elo.

Comment: Rather than passing in an empty array, can we take no input for the history?

Comment: @Giuseppe That would be okay

Comment: Section 8.54 of https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=197&view=article might be of use. Rating difference of >400 is treated as =400

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 106 bytes

This assumes the history never contains a zero.

```matlab
@(h,r,s)(h=[1e3,h])(n=nnz(h))+((40-(20*(n>30)))-(10*((n>30)&(max(h)>2401))))*(s-(1/(1+10^((r-h(n))/400))))
```

This outputs (after some formatting):

```matlab
Correct - Calculated
1038    - 1037.87
1705    - 1705.3
2497    - 2496.51
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1dFNbsIwEAXgPafIpmUGkjDjn4QugipxDKBSBImCRE0V0qrq5VPnIZUz1AvL77Mtz8jX41B/NWNb5Xk@vlKX9umNqat22ti0OzCFKoQf6piXRE4yMrKgsLHCzBlpDPf0TO/1dzy2MU407vGCbnF/RbpUeSPqs44C88rJdJPH9qM/h6Gl@fba981xSLJkW1@On5d6aE77MOfZ3wkVu07iyJKn8z5oKf6RjHspH2metrQ7pIl6kThzGpuaRVJBFuOn2WNdTmuFK1zhCjdwAzdwA7dwC7dwC3dwB3dwB7/X4eEe7uEFvIAX8AJewkvjpyZQtPynJtaTGNQTH5TYhEERkvv45b8)

---

Note: According to the FIDE-scoring system: If you play 41 games against a player having a score of 5000 (more than 2000 points higher than the highest achieved score ever), you'll end up with a score of **2400**. I believe that fewer scores than 30, and a maximum score higher than 2400 should be considered invalid input (but that's OP's decision).

[Check it here](https://tio.run/##LY5NCsIwEIX3OUU26oxNcaJxY0nxAp5AKoQ2IQFNJakiXr5W6@597wde3w7macfR6SN4kURG8Pos7U74BiHqGN/gEQsARSVsaQ2x3hEiliAnmGkJN/OaavVWkZwyXEOe8g3IQtIFIJUeIuJG0XeJFctaVizpPRFVjHmuufxJ1ycewhcPSv78sxfuf6ypmI0dc/cU4uBgdTKvcDNXnts@WW7cYBNXxFP/iF0@8EVYifkWjuMH)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), 124 bytes

This is a valid JavaScript anonymous function. Add `f=` at the beginning and invoke like `f(arg1,arg2,arg3)`. Assumes that the first element of history is not 0 (which is allowed).

```
(a,r,s)=>(e=a.some(c=>c>2400),a=a[0]?a:[1e3],Math.round((y=a.pop())+((a.length<30?40:(e?20:10))*(s-1/(1+10**((r-y)/400))))))
```

```js
let f=
(a,r,s)=>(e=a.some(c=>c>2400),a=a[0]?a:[1e3],Math.round((y=a.pop())+((a.length<30?40:(e?20:10))*(s-1/(1+10**((r-y)/400))))))


btnTrigger.onclick = () => {
  let a = inputA.value.split`,`.map(c=>parseInt(c,10)),   
      r = parseInt(inputR.value,10),
      s = parseFloat(inputS.value,10);
  
  console.log(f(a,r,s));
}
```

```html
<p>Add a Single Comma in History input box for empty History</p>

<input type="text" id="inputA" placeholder="Comma Separated History">
<input type="text" id="inputR" placeholder="Value for R1">
<input type="text" id="inputS" placeholder="Value for S">

<button type="button" id="btnTrigger">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Your calculations seem to be wrong, for `[2256,25,1253,1278,443,789], 3999, 0.5` the output should be 809

Comment: @Tom Fixed. It was something wrong with Test Snippet (it was parsing `0.5` as 0). And I have added the rounding part too. It really costed me a lot!

Comment: Nice, looks good now!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 106 bytes

```python
def f(h,b,s):a=([1e3]+h)[-1];return round(a+((len(h)<30)*4or-~(max(h)<2400))*10*(s-1/(1+10**((b-a)/400))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1dFNTsMwEAXgPafwcpwf6vFPggqcxPIiVROlEjiV40qw4erBfpwCL0ZP3yz8pLl/53WL5jiu8yIWWrtLt8vz9E6eZxPaVfqew2ua8yNFkbZHvNLUEn3MkVb5ZpRs7Jb6H/qcvipoq5SUDauG9p5PxG2JDdGln@QJOymPZUsiz3sWtyi896ET7JQqM3Tes0JU2tXpkMeaGc5whjNcwzVcwzXcwA3cwA3cwi3cwi38r4KDO7iDD/ABPsAH@Agftav9UVr9k/4vVTT6lA9La6FRQj27EM5Porx7usVMCzX1TuVkvw)

---

**without rounding, 98 bytes**:

```python
def f(h,b,s):a=([1e3]+h)[-1];return((len(h)<30)*4or-~(max(h)<2400))*10*(s-1/(1+10**((b-a)/400)))+a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1dFNTsMwEIbhPafwcpwfOuOfBBU4ieVFKhKlEiSV40plw9VD/HEKvBiNHi/8Sr5953ld7L5/jJOaaG4uzabPwzsFGW2sZx1aia9pzPe0EH2OC836zbKu3JraH/oaHgWMY9a6Eq5oa@VEUh9rRXRpB33Cna6HfVqTyuOW1XVRIYTYKPHMx4xNCMJY2fgyPfa@7AIXuMAFbuAGbuAGbuEWbuEW7uAO7uAO/pfg4R7u4R28g3fwDt7De@NLP6L5n/S/FDHoOR48qpVBBD/7GM9P6ji3dF0yTVSVf9J6/wU)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 109 bytes

```r
function(p,s,h=1000,l=length(h))round(h[l]+`if`(l<30,40,`if`(any(h>2400),10,20))*(s-1/(1+10^((p-h[l])/400))))
```

Returns an anonymous function that takes several arguments: `p`, player 1's rating, `s`, the score of the game, and `h`, the history. Technically takes another argument `l` but it defaults to the length of `h`. `h` defaults to `1000` so if there is no historical record of games, no value is provided for `h`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1dHBbsIwDAbgO0@xowMBbCduOdC9CGJiYitBqgJq4cDTd8m/pyCH6M@nRLaVce67uX/m8@N6y3T3k0@dMLMfuuE3Xx6JknPj7Zl/KB2G4@p07U807AP7yB6H7/yi9KmR2Xlhr@zckqa1bElWwl9E93V96bb1RllzT2KlgLjFosRai/35P3wIq9XdkNuaBS5wgQtc4QpXuMIDPMADPMAjPMIjPMINbnCDG7yBN/AG3sBbeKvmMIDWPnhj7zHCroqin1Kw/Mf8Bw)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 105 bytes

```
(h,r,s,u=h.length?h.pop():1e3,k=h.length>28?h.some(v=>v>2400)?10:20:40)=>u+k*s-k/(1+10**((r-u)/400))+.5|0
```

Answer (score 1):

## oK, 66 bytes

```
{*|x+_.5+(40-(10*2+|/2399<x)*29<#x)*z-1%1+exp((y-*|x)%400)*log 10}
```

[Try it online.](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/?run=f%3A%7B%2a%7Cx%2B_.5%2B%2840-%2810%2a2%2B%7C%2F2399%3Cx%29%2a29%3C%23x%29%2az-1%251%2Bexp%28%28y-%2a%7Cx%29%25400%29%2alog%2010%7D%0A%0Aa%3Af%5B1000%2C1025%2C1050%2C1075%2C1100%2C1125%2C1150%2C1175%2C1200%2C1225%2C1250%2C1275%2C1300%2C1325%2C1350%2C1375%2C1400%2C1425%2C1450%2C1475%2C1500%2C1525%2C1550%2C1575%2C1600%2C1625%2C1650%2C1800%2C2100%2C2500%3B2200%3B0.5%5D%20%2F2497%0A%0Aa%2C%3Af%5B2256%2C25%2C1253%2C1278%2C443%2C789%3B3999%3B0.5%5D%20%2F809%0A%0Aa%2C%3Af%5B1543%2C2937%2C2267%2C556%2C445%2C2489%2C2741%2C3200%2C528%2C964%2C2346%2C3467%2C2831%2C3746%2C3824%2C2770%2C3207%2C613%2C2675%2C1692%2C2537%2C1715%2C3018%2C2760%2C2162%2C2038%2C2637%2C741%2C1849%2C41%2C193%2C458%2C2292%2C222%2C2997%3B3814%3B0.5%5D%20%2F3002%0A%0Aa)

For regular k, add two bytes by turning `log` and `exp` into `` `log `` and `` `exp `` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell 158 bytes

```
g h o s=round$p+k*(s-1/(1+10**((o-p)/400)))
 where
 p=if(l h<1)then 1000else last h
 k=40-(if(l h)>=30then 20else 0)-if(any(>=2400)h)then 10else 0
 l=length
```

`g` is a function that takes a list `h` representing the `h`istory of the player, `o`, the `o`pponent points and,`s` the  `s`core of the game.